# Need Help Creating runnable Jar file for a Java FX Application

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I am having an issue with trying to create a runnable Jar file for a Java FX Application I built using Eclipse Neon and Java 1.8.  When I attempt to generate the Runnable Jar from Eclipse via the Runnable Jar File Specification dialog box, I get the error message: "Could not find main method from given launch configuration."

I am specifying the main class in the "Launch Configuration" pull down menu.

Appreciate any help with this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `build.fxbuild` file in the root of your project. Right click that an click `Build Export FX Application`. Your jar will be located in `<project>/build/dist`

Comment: Hi Zeron01alpha, there isn't one.  I did a linux find, and my project does not have that file.  Maybe I didn't create my JavaFX project properly?

Comment: @user1104028 How did you create it? I use the Java FX project template, `File -> New -> Other... -> JavaFX -> JavaFX Project`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding a public void main() defined within your application, thusly:

```
public class myApplication extends Application
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }

  public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception
  {
    ...
  }
}
```